# Plotting Kernel Density Estimates on Same Axes in R

Tags: r, kernel-smoothing

Here:

https://www.python-graph-gallery.com/74-density-plot-of-several-variables

Python's `seaborn` library is used to illustrate how to plot multiple kernel density estimates (KDEs) on the same set of axes using the famous `iris` dataset. However, it seems to ignore the fact that the plots should be computed using the same bandwidth.

I have two datasets that I need to plot in R using `density()`, but believe I should ensure the curves have the same bandwidth.

Is it necessary to ensure this? That is, what are the statistical consequences of not ensuring this? Could someone illustrate with an example?

Comment: R allows the bandwidth to be set manually as in `x<-rnorm(10^3);plot(density(x,bw=0.234))` though whether this is better than two different default automatic bandwidths is another question

Comment: @Henry Sure, but how would one know which of the two bandwidths to use for both plots? The data would have to be plotted on the same fine grid of points, I believe. In your example `bw=0.234` may not be the optimal choice.

Comment: I was just trying to show you can do this manually in R, and so ensure both plots use the same bandwidth.  I chose $0.234$ as an arbitrary example, though for that sample size and distribution it turns out to be close to R's default choice - but would be different with a larger sample size or another distribution. You could do your own calculation of what is best and then set the two bandwidths equal to that number

Comment: While not essential to answer, I'd be curious to hear why you think the bandwidths should be identical.  An appropriate choice of bandwidth depends on the shape of the distribution and the sample size.  If one "believes" in an automatic choice for the bandwidth, why then insist on the same bandwidth?  You can get the automatic bandwidth with `d1=density(x1); d1$bw` and the same for the second set.  You could then take the average, the minimum, or maximum of the two bandwidths and then run `density` on both data sets.

Comment: My post at https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/428083/919 shows how to study the effects of varying bandwidth on the KDW and includes `R` code to specify the bandwidth.  The code at https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/438972/919 deals with the same problem of using the same bandwidth to compare KDEs.